# Mongoose - Update nested array using array filters

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I want to update a field that’s contained inside a nested array. The field name is `productRole`. Am using `@nestjs/mongoose`

Below is the schema

```
@Schema()
class UserProductInstances {
  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ProductInstance',
  })
  productInstance: string;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ProductRole',
  })
  productRole: string;
}

@Schema()
class UserCompanyDocument {

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company',
  })
  companyId: Company;

  @Prop()
  productInstances: UserProductInstances[];
}


@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
})
export class User {
  @Prop()
  username: string;

  @Prop()
  companies: UserCompanyDocument[];
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Below is the code I have setup to update the field with the help of array filters

```
async updateProductRole(roleId, userId, companyId, productInstanceId) {
    try {
      const result = await this.userRepo.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          _id: userId,
          'companies.companyId': companyId,
          'companies.productInstances.productInstance': productInstanceId,
        },
        {
          $set: {
            'companies.$[c].productInstances.$[p].productRole': roleId,
          },
        },
        {
          arrayFilters: [
            { 'c.companyId': companyId },
            { 'p.productInstance': productInstanceId },
          ],
          new: true, // To return the updated document
        },
      );

      if (!result) {
        console.log(
          'User not found or product not found for this user and company.',
        );
      } else {
        console.log('ProductRole updated successfully');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating productRole:', error);
    }
```

This is the error am getting when i run the code above

```
Error updating productRole: Error: Could not find path "companies.0.productInstances.0.productInstance" in schema
    at _castArrayFilters
```

How can i fix the error above and carry out an update of the field?